# Customize Grails stats

Tags: grails, grails-3.3

When `grails stats` is executed it gives statistics of sources as per grails default convention. How can I customize stats to add some of my custom classes under `src` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **grails create-script mystats**, this will create file mystats.groovy under src/main/scripts folder
2. look at https://github.com/grails/grails-profile-repository/blob/master/profiles/base/commands/stats.groovy - original stats script code
3. put it into mystats.groovy and customize **pathToInfo**
4. run **grails mystats**

Comment: Is it possible to extend it rather than copying the whole stats file?

Comment: Looks like no. You can create pull request with improvenments)

Comment: Thanks. For the time being script copy should be enough :)